# Magento 2 onepage checkout validation issue

Tags: magento2, checkout, onepage-checkout, form-validation, onestepcheckout

I'm using IWD onepage checkout module. Everything working fine. I also integrated porto magento 2 theme with it. When I try to checkout I get state as required field even though if I selected it. I ran all required magento 2 commands.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same issue. I found a way around it, but it is not the right way. I disabled state being a required value: Configuration --> General --> State Options --> deselect the countries highlighted.
After that it will work. Hopefully that'll help until someone can provide the correct way to do it.
I have discovered one new issue, but I'm not sure if it is due to this change or not. Now if the customer tries to choose Billing and Shipping address are not the same it comes up with another error.
I'm not sure if it's possible, but it seems now IWD has a new checkout these new issues seem to be appearing. Not sure if they can make that happen or just a coincidence?